# Specify an array index type

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

How can I specify an array index and sub-index type? **Note:** I will use it with PHPStorm.

**Array example**:

```
function name ($options) {
    // $options['length']        => integer
    // $options['more']          => array
    // $options['more']['test1'] => boolean
    // $options['more']['test2'] => boolean
}
```

**Example** (*that not works*):

```
/**
 * @param array $options
 *      @var int   $length
 *      @var array $more
 *          @var bool $test1
 *          @var bool $test2
 */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, PhpStorm only support simple syntax, just as Sam has stated, e.g.

```
/**
 * @param string[] $options
 */
```

The code above described parameter which is array of strings.

---

Install **Options completion plugin** -- it supports new proposed syntax for hashes (describing array keys and its' types) in PHPDoc: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#7-describing-hashes

This plugin will add code completion for array keys.

```
<?php
class Element {
    /**
     * Initializes this class with the given options.
     *
     * @param array $options {
     *     @var bool   $required Whether this element is required
     *     @var string $label    The display name for this element
     * }
     */
    public function __construct(array $options = array())
    {
        // some code here
    }
}


new Element(['label' => 'Bob', '|' ]);
//                              | Ctrl+Space will show supported attributes
```

**NOTE:** Main purpose of this plugin is to offer array keys completion -- I'm not sure how well it supports type resolutions for each of array elements (in case if they are different like in your example).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, [according to the docs](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/types.html#arrays), that it's only possible to define an array as a set of one specific type (instead of setting a type for each index):

```
/**
 * @param string[] $options
 */
```

---

The better solution would probably be to make `$options` a class, so `length` and `test1` could be properties with default values and pre-defined types.